# Encrypt compressed data using zlib and cryptojs

Tags: node.js, zlib, cryptojs

I'm in node js, trying to compress an object using **zlib.deflate** and then encrypt it using **cryptojs** **AES**.

Then, when I try to get the original value, I fail on the **zlib.inflate** call with the error: **"incorrect header check"**.

```
const zlib = require('zlib');
const { AES, enc } = require('crypto-js');

const obj = {
    a: "a",
    b: "b"
};

const inputToDeflate = JSON.stringify(obj);
const compressed = zlib.deflateSync(inputToDeflate);
const encrypted = AES.encrypt(compressed.toString(), 'f11').toString();


const decrypted = AES.decrypt(encrypted, 'f11');
const decompressed = zlib.inflateSync(decrypted.toString(enc.Utf8));
```

Comment: Compressed data is binary, but `Buffer.toString()` treats it as UTF8, which destroys much of it, and encrypt by default _encodes_ it as UTF8 which is also harmful (though it could be recovered). Use `enc.Latin1.parse(compressed.toString('latin1'))`. And similarly for the decrypted WordArray use `.toString(enc.Latin1)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're losing zlib header when converting it to string before encryption. We need to change this `compressed.toString()` some way that the header still preserve inside, something like base64 encoding.

```
const buffer = Buffer.from(compressed).toString("base64")
const encrypted = AES.encrypt(buffer, 'f11').toString();
```

Decryption is remind the same, but we need to decode the result back from base64 to original zlib data like before.

```
const decrypted = AES.decrypt(encrypted, 'f11').toString(enc.Utf8);
const decryptedBuffer = Buffer.from(decrypted,'base64')
const decompressed = zlib.inflateSync(decryptedBuffer);

const resultString = decompressed.toString()
```

That's it. But I have suggestion here to do encryption part first before compression. Because the result string is different. Take a look in this full code :

**Full Code**

```
const zlib = require('zlib');
const { AES, enc } = require('crypto-js');

const obj = {
    a: "a",
    b: "b"
};

const inputToDeflate = JSON.stringify(obj);
const compressed = zlib.deflateSync(inputToDeflate);

// Compact the data to base64
const buffer = Buffer.from(compressed).toString("base64")
const encrypted = AES.encrypt(buffer, 'f11').toString();

console.log("compressed + base64 + encrypted length",encrypted.length)

const decrypted = AES.decrypt(encrypted, 'f11').toString(enc.Utf8);

// Convert the result from base64 to original compressed data
const decryptedBuffer = Buffer.from(decrypted,'base64')
const decompressed = zlib.inflateSync(decryptedBuffer);

// Convert buffer to string
const resultString = decompressed.toString()

// vice versa
console.log(resultString)
```

Output:

```
compressed + base64 + encrypted length 88
{"a":"a","b":"b"}
```

**Suggestion**

```
const zlib = require('zlib');
const { AES, enc } = require('crypto-js');

const obj = {
    a: "a",
    b: "b"
};

const inputData = JSON.stringify(obj);
const encrypted = AES.encrypt(inputData, 'f11').toString();
const compressed = zlib.deflateSync(encrypted);

console.log("encrypted + compressed length",encrypted.length)

const decompressed = zlib.inflateSync(compressed);
const decrypted = AES.decrypt(decompressed.toString(), 'f11').toString(enc.Utf8);

console.log(decrypted)
```

Output:

```
encrypted + compressed length 64
{"a":"a","b":"b"}
```

I think it much more efficient to do encryption first and then compression.

Comment: Um, no. Encrypted data can't be compressed. It is a waste of time to attempt to do so. Compress before encryption, when there might be something compressible.

Comment: @MarkAdler: in general yes, but cryptojs encryption returns a `CipherParams` object whose default formatter, used by `toString()` with no argument, encodes in base64, which of course can be compressed by 25% minus epsilon -- although avoiding the encoding entirely is at least as effective and faster, given binary output is desired or acceptable.

Comment: You would still want to compress before encryption. After base64 encoding, if you want the compactness of a binary representation, then it is more efficient and far less time consuming to simply base64 decode it than it would be to compress it. Compression after encryption in that case is just as silly.